# Same product showing multiple times in the product list page

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app, shopware6-api

We are currently experiencing an issue on the product listing page when using the Top Seller sorting option. The problem is that products are showing up multiple times on different pages.

For example, we have a variant product named "Demo 1" listed in "Demo category 1." On the initial page of the category, everything appears as expected, and "Demo 1" is correctly displayed. However, when navigating to the second page, "Demo 1" reappears.

As someone new to Shopware, I'm finding it challenging to resolve this pagination problem. Can anyone provide guidance on how to address this issue and ensure that products, such as "Demo 1," are displayed correctly across different pages within a category?

It's worth mentioning that this problem is only occurring when using the Top Seller sorting option. We have already disabled all third-party plugins and themes to confirm that the issue is within the core.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have update the question

Answer (score 0):

The described problem was fixed recently with this commit:
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/commit/67390beb8f9eac9ca30d309dc332c8c13f58e7cb

A default sorting is now added, if a sorting is missing in the criteria, which should make the result deterministic again.

It will be part of the upcoming version 6.5.8.0 and 6.6.0.0

As a workaround you can try to extend the request and add a default sorting by yourself to the then generated criteria.